# Variables are removing data from cells - Loop Help; VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 worksheets:

a) A fixture list, with all of the fixture components. 
b) A store list that has stores that have the fixture. 
c) *What I need* - Fixture List with Fixture Components, that also lists the stores that have the Fixtures.

I need to create a 3rd worksheet that has a combination of the two worksheets.  Currently I have the a find function that looks for the name of the fixture; which then creates variables based on the info needed, and it places the variables on the 3rd sheet.

But when I set the original variable information, the variable name disappears, so the next loop, the fixture name won't be caught in the search.

The store list is HUGE, and this causes the macro to run very slowly; so any help in making it more efficicent would be appreciated.

I've attached my code, because I'm not explaining this well.

```
Sub FindTest()


Dim S1 As Excel.Worksheet
Dim S2 As Excel.Worksheet
Dim S3 As Excel.Worksheet
Dim h As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim l As Long
Dim aCell As Range
Dim bCell As Range
Dim oRange As Range
Dim TitleVar As String
Dim ItemNumber As String
Dim ItemDesc As String
Dim ShipTo As String
Dim StoreNumber As String
Dim UPC As String
Dim Chain As String
Dim DivRange As Range
Dim Match As String
Dim FixtureType As String
Dim FindFixtureName As Range
Dim FindItemNumber As Range
Dim FindUPC As Range
Dim FindItemDesc As Range
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim rng1 As Range



Set S1 = Sheets("Titles")
Set S2 = Sheets("Fixtures")
Set S3 = Sheets("Import")
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set rng1 = S1.Cells.Find("*", S1.[a1], xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)


Set oRange = S1.Columns(4)

h = 2
j = 2
i = 2
K = 2
l = 2
m = 1

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
S2.Activate
S2.Columns("B:B").Select

With Selection
    Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
    .Value = .Value
End With


TitleVar = S1.Cells(K, 4)
Chain = S2.Cells(h, 1)
ShipTo = S2.Cells(h, 2)
StoreNumber = S2.Cells(h, 4)
UPC = Format(S1.Cells(K, 7), "###########")
lastRow = S1.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
StrSearch = UCase(S2.Cells(h, 6))
FixtureType = S2.Cells(h, 8)
ItemNumber = S1.Range("D" & i).Offset(0, 2)
Match = ShipTo & ItemNumber



'************** Test Worksheet


LastShipTo = S2.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1

Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "Test"

Range("A1") = "Chain"
Range("B1") = "Match"
Range("C1") = "Ship To Number"
Range("D1") = "Store #"
Range("E1") = "Item Number"
Range("F1") = "Item Description"
Range("G1") = "UPC"
Range("H1") = "Fixture"
Range("I1") = "Fixture Type"
Range("j1") = "Division"
Range("k1") = "Total"

  Range("A1:Q1").Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 6299648
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0


End With
With Selection.Font
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With

Range("A1:K1").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter



Set FindFixtureName = S1.Range("D:D").Find(What:=StrSearch, 
After:=S1.Cells(1, 4), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, 
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

 Do While FindFixtureName Is Nothing
 If FindFixtureName Is Nothing Then
    h = h + 1
    StrSearch = UCase(S2.Cells(h, 6))
    Set FindFixtureName = S1.Range("D:D").Find(What:=StrSearch, 
After:=S1.Cells(1, 4), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, 
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
  End If
Loop


Set FindItemNumber = S1.Range("D:D").Find(What:=StrSearch, 
After:=S1.Cells(1, 4), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, 
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Offset(0, 
2) Set FindUPC = S1.Range("D:D").Find(What:=StrSearch, After:=S1.Cells(1, 
4), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, 
SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Offset(0, 3)
Set FindItemDesc = S1.Range("D:D").Find(What:=StrSearch, After:=S1.Cells(1, 
4), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, 
SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Offset(0, 4)

Do Until StrSearch = ""


          Do Until FindFixtureName <> StrSearch

           Match = ShipTo & FindItemNumber
           Sheets("Test").Cells(j, 1) = Chain
           Sheets("Test").Cells(j, 2) = Match
           Sheets("Test").Cells(j, 3) = ShipTo
           Sheets("Test").Cells(j, 4) = StoreNumber
           Sheets("Test").Cells(j, 5) = FindItemNumber
           Sheets("Test").Cells(j, 6) = FindItemDesc
           Sheets("Test").Cells(j, 7) = FindUPC
           Sheets("Test").Cells(j, 8) = StrSearch
           Sheets("Test").Cells(j, 9) = FixtureType


           j = j + 1
           l = l + 1


           FindFixtureName = FindFixtureName.Offset(m, 0)
           FindItemNumber = FindItemNumber.Offset(m, 0)
           FindUPC = FindUPC.Offset(m, 0)
           FindItemDesc = FindItemDesc.Offset(m, 0)
           m = m + 1

           Loop



 TitleVar = S1.Cells(K, 4)


h = h + 1
 l = 1
 ShipTo = S2.Cells(h, 2)
 StrSearch = UCase(S2.Cells(h, 6))
 Match = ShipTo & ItemNumber
 StoreNumber = S2.Cells(h, 4)

 FindFixtureName = vbaNullString

Set FindFixtureName = S1.Range("D:D").Find(What:=StrSearch, 
After:=S1.Cells(1, 4), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, 
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

Do While FindFixtureName Is Nothing
If FindFixtureName Is Nothing Then
    h = h + 1
    StrSearch = UCase(S2.Cells(h, 6))
    Set FindFixtureName = S1.Range("D:D").Find(What:=StrSearch, 
After:=S1.Cells(1, 4), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, 
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
End If
Loop


Set FindItemNumber = S1.Range("D:D").Find(What:=StrSearch, 
After:=S1.Cells(1, 4), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, 
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Offset(0, 
2)
Set FindUPC = S1.Range("D:D").Find(What:=StrSearch, After:=S1.Cells(1, 4), 
LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, 
SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Offset(0, 3)
Set FindItemDesc = S1.Range("D:D").Find(What:=StrSearch, After:=S1.Cells(1, 
4), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, 
SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Offset(0, 4)

m = 1

Loop




lastRow = Sheets("Test").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DIV")
lR = Sheets("Div").Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Test").Range("J2: J" & lastRow).Formula = 
"=IfError(VLOOKUP(C2,Div!$A$2:$G$" & lR & ",2,0),"""")"

End With


With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Test")
RR = Sheets("Import").Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Test").Range("K2:K" & lastRow).Formula = 
"=IfError(VLOOKUP(B2,Import!$B$2:$J$" & RR & ",8,0),"""")"

Sheets("Test").Range("L1") = "0 Total"
Sheets("Test").Range("L2:L" & lastRow).Formula = "=IF(K2="""",""YES"","""")"

    Sheets("Test").Range("M1") = "1 Total"
Sheets("Test").Range("M2:M" & lastRow).Formula = "=IF(K2=1,""YES"","""")"

    Sheets("Test").Range("N1") = "2 Total"
Sheets("Test").Range("N2:N" & lastRow).Formula = "=IF(K2=2,""YES"","""")"

    Sheets("Test").Range("O1") = "3+ Total"
Sheets("Test").Range("O2:O" & lastRow).Formula = "=IF(K2>=3,""YES"","""")"

    Sheets("Test").Range("P1") = "Dup Store Match"
Sheets("Test").Range("P2:P" & lastRow).Formula = "=D2&"" ""&H2"

    Sheets("Test").Range("Q1") = "Dup Store Count"
Sheets("Test").Range("Q2:Q" & lastRow).Formula = "=IF(P3=P2,""DUP"","""")"

End With


'******  End of Find




Sheets("Test").Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit


Sheets("Test").Activate

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic



MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: You're repeating your Find() multiple times unnecessarily - do it *once* to get a reference to the found row, then pull the items you need from that row.

Comment: But do you see why when i set a variable, it erases it from the sheet?

Comment: Which exact variable?

Comment: FindFixtureName.   When I go back to the "Title" Tab after i run the report, Column "D" (The Column that has the Fixture Names)  is completely blank.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
 FindFixtureName = FindFixtureName.Offset(m, 0)
```

`FindFixtureName` is a Range object, so this code is equivalent to writing:

```
 FindFixtureName.Value = FindFixtureName.Offset(m, 0).Value
```

Possibly what you wanted was:

```
 Set FindFixtureName = FindFixtureName.Offset(m, 0)
```

which actually moves the `FindFixtureName` range down by `m` rows

EDIT: also here

```
FindFixtureName = vbaNullString
```

you are clearing the content of that cell

Comment: That Almost works... It doesn't erase every Fixture Name, but it erases the first Fixture Name, when it originally sets it as the variable. 

Is it possible to set each fixture as  an array? Wouldn't that be a more efficient macro?

Comment: See my edit.  Yes your code could be more efficient but I don't have time to go through it all...